# ACF Repeater showing ID, not URL

Tags: php, url, foreach, repeater, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using the Advanced Custom Fields Repeater to pump out the image URL. But, it shows the ID, not the URL. Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks. Here is my code:

```
<?php 
$rows = get_field('images');

foreach($rows as $row){
$image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_sub_field('image'), 'full');

//var_dump($row['image']);
echo  '<img src="'. $row['image']['url'] . '" class="shadowed forced">';
}

?>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Looks like what I needed to do was *not* use a foreach, and instead just use and if & while statement. I was calling in the repeater, not the subfield with the old code. Here's a reference if anyone runs into this issue -

```
  <?php 
  $rows = get_field('images');

  if ($rows) 
  {
    while (has_sub_field('images')) 
    {  
      $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_sub_field('image'), 'full');
      echo '<img src="'. $image[0] . '" class="shadowed forced">';
    }
  } 
  ?>
```

Comment: So pretty much you used my answer bellow?

Answer (score 2):

In response to your question, it doesn't work because `get_sub_field` has to be used in a `while` statement in conjunction with `has_sub_field()`, and because your `$row['image']['url']` is referring to an the image object (set via [return value](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/field-types/image/#creating-an%20image%20field) on the field menu), while is seems as if you are actually having the field return the 'Attachment ID'.

If you want to use a foreach with the [return value](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/field-types/image/#creating-an%20image%20field) set to 'Attachment ID', you need to use the object/array that is being returned like so:

```
<?php 
$rows = get_field('images');

foreach($rows as $row){
$image = wp_get_attachment_image_src($row['image'], 'full');

echo  '<img src="'. $image[0] . '" class="shadowed forced">';
}

?>
```

If you want to use the foreach method, with the [return value](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/field-types/image/#creating-an%20image%20field) set to 'Image Object', it should look something like this:

```
<?php 
$rows = get_field('images');

foreach($rows as $row){


echo  '<img src="'. $row['image']['url'] . '" class="shadowed forced">';
}?>
```

Another solution, working of your answer/suggestion would be to set the fields [return value](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/field-types/image/#creating-an%20image%20field) to 'Image URL', and then you could simply call the image like so:

```
 <?php $rows = get_field('images');

if ($rows) 
{
 while (has_sub_field('images')) 
{  
 $image = get_sub_field('image');
  echo '<img src="'. $image . '" class="shadowed forced">';
}
 } ?>
```

Alternatively if you wanted to show a different size of the image, you could also set the 'Return Value' to 'Image Object', and do something like this:

```
<?php $rows = get_field('images');

if ($rows) 
{
 while (has_sub_field('images')) 
{  
 $image = get_sub_field('image');
  echo '<img src="'. $image['sizes']['large'] . '" class="shadowed forced">';
}
 } ?>
```